# Moved site on same server and lost all files in file manager and file upload prefs

Tags: file-uploads, file-manager

I have a subdomain “dev.” where the site was working fine. I then created a new subdomain on the same server called “staging” and copied all my site files from dev into that. I also created a new database for staging and imported everything from dev into that.

I followed the migration instructions as I always do, exactly. https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/operations/moving.html

Updated all paths, etc. But for some reason, none of the images show on the site that were uploaded to directories. All of the images exist in their appropriate folders on “staging.”

However, there is nothing in my file upload preferences and nothing in my file manager. It’s as if everything disappeared.

If I try to recreate an upload directory in file upload prefs, i get this error “An Error Was Encountered The name of your directory is already taken.”

Also, when I looked in the exp_files table in the db, all the rel_paths still have the “dev” name associated with it.

I checked and re-checked everything, all my paths are correct in config, all of my directories have the correct permissions. I’m at a loss at this point.

EE 2.11.2 on a Windows Server.

I never work on a windows server with EE, but in this instance I had to. It has been nothing but a pain. Any help in the right direction is much appreciated at this point.

Comment: Did you try to synchronize the folders in the file manager?

Answer (score 0):

I did, and after further diving I found that my exp_upload_prefs table was empty. That was the last table in my “staging” db. I checked my “dev” db and there was one more table after that “exp_wygwam_configs.”

So the db import wasn’t 100% successful. I went through and checked each table to see what else was missing, looks like that was the only table issue. Not sure what caused the bad import. Not a huge fan of this windows hosting on hostgator.

Comment: I had one client who was with a host that was "set up and running Apache and MySQL.  I found out later it was on Windows.  I have never had so many quirks with an EE site as I had while running on Windows.  I finally moved it to a LAMP host and life has been good ever since.

Comment: I hear ya, in this situation I had to. Even once before I had a client insist on windows and it was the simplest of sites, still nothing but quirks with EE on it. Definitely go LAMP whenever possible with EE.